# Unable to locate package vulkan for GPU Nvidia GeForce?

Tags: linux, gpu, vulkan

Why I can't install vulkan? Maybe because it's not compatible with my GPU Nvidia GeForce?

```
@ubuntu:~$ sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:09:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001140sv0000103Csd00002337bc03sc02i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (GeForce 820M)
driver   : nvidia-driver-450 - third-party free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

I'm receiving this error during vulkan instalation:

```
@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt install vulkan
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package vulkan
```

**Extra information about my GPU**

```
@ubuntu:~$ glxinfo -B
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: Intel (0x8086)
    Device: Mesa Intel(R) HD Graphics 5500 (BDW GT2) (0x1616)
    Version: 20.3.0
    Accelerated: yes
    Video memory: 3072MB
    Unified memory: yes
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 4.6
    Max compat profile version: 4.6
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.2
OpenGL vendor string: Intel
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa Intel(R) HD Graphics 5500 (BDW GT2)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 20.3.0-devel (git-3d5bed0 2020-09-07 focal-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile

OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 20.3.0-devel (git-3d5bed0 2020-09-07 focal-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 20.3.0-devel (git-3d5bed0 2020-09-07 focal-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20



@ubuntu:~$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09)
```

Where could I find more information about GPU compatibility?

Comment: The simple answer is that the package is not called "vulkan"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure if you can install vulkan like that,
because vulkan is a lib but you must a have the gpu driver who work with?

On my ubuntu it was installed with the nvidia driver

you can found more information on this page for nvidia :
https://developer.nvidia.com/vulkan-driver

you have also general info on vulkan support here :
https://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/